# BadImageFormatException on interop from DLL build with gcc on 64-bit system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gcc, interop

I'm developing a .NET library. As a part of the task to make the library cross-platform, I decided to put all platform-specific functions to C file and build DLL (for Windows) and dylib (for macOS). To start the task I've created a simple test app: console application on Windows on .NET Framework that calls a simple function from the generated DLL.

Content of the C file the DLL (test.dll) built from:

```
int Foo() { return 123; }
```

Test program code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("test")]
    public static extern int Foo();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Foo();
        Console.WriteLine($"Result = {result}");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get **BadImageFormatException**.

If I go the project settings in Visual Studio, I see:

[image]

If I either uncheck 'Prefer 32-bit' or select x64 in the dropdown, all is fine and I see correct output:

```
Result = 123
Press any key to exit...
```

BUT that's not a solution for me. The library is used by many users and I don't want (and mustn't) to force them to do some environment setup, like selecting target platform. Also it should work on both x86 and x64.

DLL is built with gcc:

```
gcc -v -c test.c
gcc -v -shared -o test.dll test.o
```

My question is how to handle the trouble and create DLL that can be targeted in any .NET app without preliminary actions? Maybe it's possible to build a DLL with dual-platform targeting (not only x64)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with building two versions of DLL, 32-bit and 64-bit. So in code we have classes like this:

**Api.cs**

```
namespace DualLibClassLibrary
{
    internal abstract class Api
    {
        public abstract int Method();
    }
}
```

**Api32.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DualLibClassLibrary
{
    internal sealed class Api32 : Api
    {
        [DllImport("test32")]
        public static extern int Foo();

        public override int Method()
        {
            return Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

**Api64.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DualLibClassLibrary
{
    internal sealed class Api64 : Api
    {
        [DllImport("test64")]
        public static extern int Foo();

        public override int Method()
        {
            return Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

**ApiProvider.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DualLibClassLibrary
{
    internal static class ApiProvider
    {
        private static readonly bool Is64Bit = IntPtr.Size == 8;
        private static Api _api;

        public static Api Api
        {
            get
            {
                if (_api == null)
                    _api = Is64Bit ? (Api)new Api64() : new Api32();

                return _api;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So we if we want to call `Method` method, we'll write:

```
var result = ApiProvider.Api.Method();
```

And of course we need to have following files in output:

- test32.dll (and dylib, and so on)
- test64.dll (and dylib, and so on)

With this system the program will select desired file relying on whether the current process is 64-bit or not.